# Finding maximum of $y-z$ given quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qclp

## Problem

According to my friend, this is a problem that seems to be solvable *by observation*.

Try to find the maximum of $(y-z)$ given following two constraints

$$
\begin{aligned}
x+y+z=3\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=9
\end{aligned}
$$

This is a convex QCQP problem and it is solvable by some solver like cvxpy but I am not sure how do I solve this problem by observation?

Except treating it as a QCQP problem, I also tried to eliminate $z$ and finally cast it into maximizing $x+2y-3$ given
$$
x^2+y^2+2xy-3(x+y)=0\tag{1}
$$
the hope is that I factor (1) into terms of $(x+2y-3)$, but I failed to do this.

So does anyone know how to solve this, thank you in advance.

Comment: QCQP??? Where's the quadratic objective?

Comment: The feasible region is a circle (not a disk), which is as non-convex as it gets. How would CVXPY help?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Linear object is a special case of quadratic object and an extension of cvxpy could handle such problem (see [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/qcqp)).

Comment: Are you a masochist? Just use Lagrange multipliers. If you must use Python, use SymPy instead, to find the exact solutions of the resulting system of polynomial equations.

Comment: Not using anything from optimization could still solve this problem. I think even high school student could fully understand the answer provided by following, which makes it a good solution.

Comment: My updated solution shows how I believe "observation" could be used in this case, plus I give a more general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about using "observation", but here is how I would approach solving your $2$ equations of

$$x + y + z = 3 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

You can start to "complete the square" by using \eqref{eq2} - $2 \times$ \eqref{eq1} to get

$$x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 2y + z^2 - 2z = 9 - 2 \times 3 = 3 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ need a term of $1$, so adding this to both sides and then completing the square for each variable gives that

$$\left(x - 1\right)^2 + \left(y - 1\right)^2 + \left(z - 1\right)^2 = 6 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

First, note that $y - z = \left(y - 1\right) - \left(z - 1\right)$. Since each term above is squared, the solutions would involve $x - 1 = \pm m$, for some non-negative $m$, and likewise for the other $2$ terms. Also, the maximum values for $\mid y - 1 \mid$ and $\mid z - 1 \mid$ will be reached when $x = 1$ so the first term is $0$ and we then get

$$\left(y - 1\right)^2 + \left(z - 1\right)^2 = 6 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

As the MSE question at [Maximizing the sum of two numbers, the sum of whose squares is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/maximizing-the-sum-of-two-numbers-the-sum-of-whose-squares-is-constant) shows in several ways, the maximum value of the sum of absolute values is achieved when $\left(y - 1\right)^2 = \left(z - 1\right)^2 = 3$, giving $y - 1 = \sqrt{3}$ and $z - 1 = -\sqrt{3}$, for a maximum value of $y - z$ being $2\sqrt{3}$. Note \eqref{eq1} still holds as $x = 1$, $y = 1 + \sqrt{3}$ and $z = 1 - \sqrt{3}$ gives $x + y + z = 3$, plus \eqref{eq2} also holds, confirming this is a valid solution.

It's important to check the original equations since if we had instead added $2 \times$ \eqref{eq1} to \eqref{eq2} to complete the squares to get $\left(x + 1\right)^2 + \left(y + 1\right)^2 + \left(z + 1\right)^2 = 18$ and then followed the same procedure to set $x = -1$, we would have got $y + 1 = 3$ and $z + 1 = -3$ for $y - z = 6$. However, $x + y + z = -3$ in this case, so \eqref{eq1} wouldn't be true then, and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 21$, so \eqref{eq2} would also fail! Completing the squares by subtracting allows determining the maximum value of $y - z$ most easily as $x = 1$ works in that case to simplify both the resulting equation & to get a maximum result with $x, y, z$ values that still satisfy both of the original $2$ equations.

It's possible this, or something similar, is what your friend was referring to, where if they have enough knowledge & experience doing this sort of thing, then to them it's solved by "observation". However, it's of course best to ask your friend what they specifically meant.

**Update:** I think I see how this can be solved by "inspection". First, split the RHS value of \eqref{eq1} equally among the $3$ variables to do a similar linear transform of $x = x_1 + 1$, $y = y_1 + 1$ and $z = z_1 + 1$. Now, \eqref{eq1} becomes

$$x_1 + y_1 + z_1 = 0 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

Also, the LHS of \eqref{eq2} becomes, including using \eqref{eq6} after grouping,

\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 & = \left(x_1 + 1\right)^2 + \left(y_1 + 1\right)^2 + \left(z_1 + 1\right)^2 \\
& = x_1^2 + 2x_1 + 1 + y_1^2 + 2y_1 + 1 + z_1^2 + 2z_1 + 1 \\
& = x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 + 2\left(x_1 + y_1 + z_1\right) + 3 \\
& = x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 + 3 \tag{7}\label{eq7}
\end{align}

Thus, \eqref{eq2} is now

$$x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = 6 \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

The condition to maximize of $y - z = y_1 - z_1$ can now easily be done due to the special condition that allows $x_1 = 0$ in \eqref{eq8} to permit a maximum value where $y_1 = -z_1$ exactly matches the resulting condition in \eqref{eq7} when $x_1 = 0$!

More generally, if the LHS of \eqref{eq1} is $c$ & the LHS of \eqref{eq2} is $d$, the maximum value of $y - z$ would be $2\sqrt{\frac{3d \, - \, c^2}{6}}$, which simplifies to $2\sqrt{3}$ in our case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, with this approach, the general QCQP formulation is no more required and this is indeed preferable.

Comment: @Mr.Robot You are welcome. Of course, this type of approach only works in a very small set of cases but, when it does, it's preferable to using something more complicated like a QCQP formulation, as you state.